# Why was XPath dropped from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I didn't find any documentation as to why [XPath support was dropped from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782912/jquery-xpath-selection-not-working/3782949#3782949).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read this: http://ejohn.org/blog/xpath-overnight/

> I should, also, probably answer the inevitable question: “Why doesn’t
>   jQuery have an XPath CSS Selector implementation?” For now, my answer
>   is: I don’t want two selector implementations – it makes the code base
>   significantly harder to maintain, increases the number of possible
>   cross-browser bugs, and drastically increases the filesize of the
>   resulting download. That being said, I’m strongly evaluating XPath for
>   some troublesome selectors that could, potentially, provide some big
>   performance wins to the end user. In the meantime, we’ve focused on
>   optimizing the actual selectors that most people use (which are poorly
>   represented in speed tests like SlickSpeed) but we hope to rectify in
>   the future.

Comment: That article does not answer the question: it explains why jQuery does not have an implementation of its "CSS selectors engine" (a term used in this article) that uses the browser's native XPath as a backend to accelerate the performance. This is an interesting and important question in itself, as John states that XPath is faster than `getElementsByTagName`, for example. Neither why jQuery does not support XPath itself, nor why jQuery's poorly named "XPath selectors" (which do not seem to have ever actually been attempting to be XPath compatible), were removed from the library.